# Insert date/time on last modified record in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, datediff

I built a simple time clock database. The table has four columns:

- ID (autonumber)
- EmployeeID
- TimeIn (Date/Time)
- TimeOut (Date/Time).

An employee sees only a form with two buttons, Clock In and Clock Out.
Each button has an On Click event to add a new record to the table with the `fOSUserName` and `Now()` under `TimeIn` or `TimeOut`, depending on which button is clicked.

All of this works great, however, I need a report to show the number of hours worked per day. In order to get a report with accurate `DateDiff()`, the `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` data has to be on the same row. I've tried LastModified, MovePrevious/MoveNext, and IfNull and I can't get TimeOut on the same row without manually moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but you could start with something  like this:

```
update clock 
set timeOut =  Now()
where employeeId = fOsUsername()
and id in (select top 1 id from clock where employeeId = fOsUsername() 
                  and timeOut is null and timeIn > Date()-1
                  order by id desc
          )
```

Comment: I tried this and got the following Compile error: Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement. It seems to be triggered by the "id in".

Comment: @shadow2451 this is SQL, not VBA.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just getting into VBA and I haven't done much with SQL yet. Would this be inserted in the query or as an On Click procedure in the form?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
Select
    EmployeeID,
    Sum(TimeIn) As ClockIn,
    Sum(TimeOut) As ClockOut
From
    YourClockTable
Group By
    EmployeeID,
    DateValue(Nz(TimeIn, TimeOut))
```

Comment: I assume this would be in the query (sorry, I'm not familiar with SQL yet). This is giving me a parameter box to input ID when I run the report. What format should I use for the ClockIn and ClockOut text boxes on the report?

Comment: Yes, it is SQL. Just modify to fit your table name etc. and copy paste into the SQL pane. Of course, you will have to adjust the report to use this source. The values are datetime so the format to use is _h:nn_

Comment: Now I get three input boxes when running the report (ClockIn, ClockOut, and ID) and leaving them blank results in an error: "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated". Why am I getting input boxes?

Comment: You get parameter boxes when you state field names that don't exist. You listed the actual field names in your question, so - if these exist - a copy-n-paste of my SQL into a new query will work as is.